# Is volatile needed here?

Tags: java, arrays, synchronization, volatile, primitive

In the following hypotetical scenario and out of desire to better understand the language, is volatile required for the *int[]* reference?

```
public final class SO {

    private int[] ar = new int[10];  // is volatile needed here?
    private int idx = 0;

    public synchronized int get( int i ) {
        return ar[i];
    }

    public synchronized void append( final int val ) {
        if ( idx == ar.length ) {
            // array is too small, let's grow it
            final int[] prev = ar;
            ar = new int[ar.length+ar.length*20/100]
            System.arrayCopy(prev, 0, ar, 0, prev.length);
        }
        ar[idx++] = val;
    }

}
```

The only way to retrieved an *int* is trough a *synchronized* method and the only way to modify the *int[]* (including creating a new *int[]*) is also done trough a synchronized method.

I do not need to add any additional synchronization right?

Comment: You've tagged this as primitive but in fact int[] is an Object as it's a java array.

Comment: Making `ar` volatile only make assigments to `ar` (not an element inside it) a volatile write

Comment: `ar.length+ar.length*20/100` = `ar.length*6/5`

Comment: @PeterLawrey While that's true, there's no benefit to removing the readability of +20%. But that should be expressed as `ar.length*120/100` - No, actually I guess you would hit integer overflow sooner with `*120`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `volatile` not needed because it is only accessed inside synchornised methods so it is already thread safe. No further thread safety is needed in your code.

Answer (score 2):

it will would just like you said since the int is protected by the class lock - but it will be dog slow, since write and read access block each other. (see CopyOnWriteList implementation for a faster way)

Comment: I don't know if "class lock" is the accepted term, but it suggests one lock for all instances. Where as this is equivilant to a `synchronized(this){...}` block.

Comment: i think it is more common to annotate the property with @GuardedBy("this") to make it more clear. So it's more of a class level declaration than object level wher you hand in the object to lock on.

Answer (score 1):

You are fine, unless your values are accessed somewhere else without synchronization.

By the way, if you did make `ar` `volatile` instead of using synchronized methods, you would need to make `idx` volatile too.  But that still would not be sufficient synchronization because two different threads running `append` at the same time could wreak havoc.

Actually, there's another problem with using a `volatile` array: changing a value in the array does not trigger a cache synchronization.  Only reassigning the array (like you do when creating a bigger array) triggers a cache flush.

Answer (score 1):

As per  [java lang specfication](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/memory.doc.html#28330)
 having volatile add strict rules for threads(read/write from main memory), using synchronized relaxes on that little bit.